# Python - confusion in how to code for reading file for updating a dynamic dictionary for lookup

Tags: python, django, linux

I'm a total noob in python: How would i refactor the code below so that the dictionary **d** is actually a file on the filesystem that gets appended to by an email and the next incremental int id if a new email addresses is found in fr?

This is the **fr** file's file structure:

```
7@comp1.COM|4|11|GDSPV
7@comp1.COM|16|82|GDSPV
13@comp1.COM|16|82|GDSPV
```

The below is my program.. it masks email addresses with ids.
 Notice that currently, I have hard-coded the d dictionary.

```
   d= {
    '7@comp1.COM': '199',
    '8@comp4.COM': '200',
    '13@comp1.COM': '205'
    }

fr = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
fw = open("masked_"+sys.argv[1], 'w')

cnt = 0
i = 1
line_list = []


for line in fr:
    columns = line.split("|")
    looking_for = columns[0] # this is what we need to search
    if looking_for in d:
        # by default, iterating over a dictionary will return keys
        new_line = d[looking_for]+'|'+'|'.join(columns[1:])
        line_list.append(new_line)
fw.writelines(line_list)

fr.close()
fw.close()
```

Also I would like to send multiple files through this program. Hundreds of them using wild card or somthing (*) for the fr file reader. Can you include that in the solution is possible. THANKS!!!

Comment: Where do I go from here? How would i refactor the code above so that d dictionary is actually a file on the filesystem that gets appended if new email addresses come in fr?

Comment: have you explored `pickle` to save dictionary to file?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the python [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) module. It is a dictionary-type object that is persistant to the filesystem (using pickle under the hood).

```
import shelve

filename = sys.argv[1]
d = shelve.open(filename)

d.update({
    '7@comp1.COM': '199',
    '8@comp4.COM': '200',
    '13@comp1.COM': '205'
})

d.close()

d = shelve.open(filename)
print d
#{'8@comp4.COM': '200', '7@comp1.COM': '199', '13@comp1.COM': '205'}

d.keys()
#['8@comp4.COM', '13@comp1.COM', '7@comp1.COM']

d['13@comp1.COM']
#'205'
```

Answer (score 0):

`I would like to maintain and persist the dictionary d in a file.`

[pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)

`Also I would like to send multiple files through this program.`

[glob](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html)

Answer (score 0):

I coded the solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

d = {}

line_list=[]
fr = open(sys.argv[2], 'r')
fw = open(sys.argv[3]+"/masked_"+sys.argv[1], 'w')

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
       (key, val) = line.split()
       d[key] = val

for line in fr:
    columns = line.split("|")
    looking_for = columns[0] # this is what we need to search
    if looking_for in d:
        # by default, iterating over a dictionary will return keys
        new_line = d[looking_for]+'|'+'|'.join(columns[1:])
        line_list.append(new_line)
    else:
        new_idx = str(len(d)+1)
        d[looking_for] = new_idx
        kv = open(sys.argv[3], 'r+')
        kv.write(looking_for+" "+new_idx)
        kv.close()
        new_line = d[looking_for]+'|'+'|'.join(columns[1:])
        line_list.append(new_line)

fw.writelines(line_list)
```